# adding login to a lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I was wondering how would I add a login to a jQuery light box? Would PHP be reqired? or Just the action link that is on the form element? `<form action="">` I will be using fancybox for the lightbox

Answer (score 1):

Where is your database of logins? Most systems store logins in a relational database. You can't access databases from the client's browser with javascript. You must use a backend technology like PHP, Java, .net, etc.

I am not sure I understand your question, did that answer it?

Comment: Please restate your question to clarify it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use database mean php is required else need not. form action is enough to create login light box. Try this http://www.webtrickss.com/javascript/login-form-using-jquery-light-box/